# C# replace XML node with a new attribute and subnode

Tags: c#, xml

I've got this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="MyApp.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup>
<applicationSettings>
    <MyApp.Settings>
        ...
        ...
    </XNet.XManager.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

I need to replace the `<startup>` node with:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
</startup>
```

Which is the best way?

Comment: Well I'd use LINQ to XML to read the whole document, replace the element you're interested, then write it out again. Have you tried that or anything similar?

Comment: No I prefer to don't use LINQ

Comment: What have you tried so far? And you should look into LINQ. It can be scary at first, but its incredibly powerful.

Comment: @Sethi: Why? I suspect your reason won't hold water in the long run. The code using LINQ to XML will be simpler than the equivalent using XmlDocument.

Answer (score 2):

If you use LINQ to XML (it's an XML API rather than LINQ):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("dat.xml");

XElement startup1 = doc.Root.Element("startup");
startup1.Remove();

doc.Root.Add(new XElement("startup", new XAttribute("useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy", "true"),
                               new XElement("supportedRuntime", new XAttribute("version", "v4.0"),
                               new XAttribute("sku", ".NETFramework"),
                               new XAttribute("Version", "v4.5.2"))));

doc.Save("dat.xml");
```

Edit - as Jon Skeet suggested the proper way should be to use [`XElement.ReplaceWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.replacewith(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("dat.xml");

XElement startup1 = doc.Root.Element("startup");           
startup1.ReplaceWith(new XElement("startup", new XAttribute("useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy", "true"),
                               new XElement("supportedRuntime", new XAttribute("version", "v4.0"),
                               new XAttribute("sku", ".NETFramework"),
                               new XAttribute("Version", "v4.5.2"))));

doc.Save("dat.xml");
```

Comment: Possibly nicer - use `XElement.ReplaceWith`, so it stays in the same location.

Comment: Oh sorry.. Just doc.Save("dat.xml")... ok.. But: the original version was "<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />" but your code replace the ".NETFramework,Version=.." without the comma: "sku=".NETFramework Version=v4.5.2"

Comment: Auto answer ;-) :                     doc.Root.Add(new XElement("startup", new XAttribute("useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy", "true"),
                                                   new XElement("supportedRuntime", new XAttribute("version", "v4.0"),
                                                   new XAttribute("sku", ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"))));

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to do the same, where the element is being find and it is replaced with other.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("path to your file");

string strXml = 
  @"<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy='true'>
    <supportedRuntime version='v4.0' sku='.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2' />
</startup>";
XmlDocumentFragment xmlDocFragment = xmlDoc.CreateDocumentFragment();
xmlDocFragment.InnerXml = strXml;
xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("startup").AppendChild(xmlDocFragment);
```

Update: Using `LINQ`. Working Tested Code

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"path to file");
string input = @"<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy='true'>
<supportedRuntime version='v4.0' sku='.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2' />
</startup>";
var replacement = XElement.Parse(input);
var nodeToReplace = doc.Descendants().Elements("startup").FirstOrDefault();
nodeToReplace.ReplaceWith(replacement);
doc.Save(@"path to file");
Console.WriteLine(doc);
Console.Read();
```

Comment: That code won't compile. After fixing it, I'd say it's also significantly less elegant than LINQ to code constructing the elements programmatically.

Comment: Nope, that's still not going to compile. It's not a valid verbatim string literal.